# Get the string inside objectId

Tags: mongodb

I have mongoId like this :

```
ObjectId("53056c1e211b6f2e5d8b4567")
```

I only want

```
"53056c1e211b6f2e5d8b4567"
```

I tried `toString` but it returns the whole thing as string.
 I know I can extract using string operations, but is there a native way to do so ?

Comment: Why do you want only "53056c1e211b6f2e5d8b4567"? What is your use case?

Comment: I have users and posts collections . 
I want to find posts by users so I grab the id of a user and it fills the author field in posts.

Comment: You could even query it by ObjectId. As far as I know all the MongoDB drivers support querying using object id. In java you could so something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797935/how-to-query-documents-using-id-field-in-java-mongodb-driver

Comment: I don't fully understand your sayings..
author is a string field that has the value of and id object of an other collection.
it is not stored as objectid but as string .. 
nevertheless , I got my answer , thanks :)

Comment: Oh!! My bad.. I thought that it was saved as object id in your posts collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it:

```
ObjectId("53056c1e211b6f2e5d8b4567").valueOf()
```

it have to return the following string:

```
53056c1e211b6f2e5d8b4567
```

For more details, see [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/)