# How to update a document in MongoDB using ObjectID in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

What I am trying to accomplish here is pretty simple. I am trying to update a single document in MongoDB collection. When I look up the document using any field, such as "name", the update query succeeds. Here is the query:

```
mongoDB.getCollection("restaurants").updateOne(
    new BasicDBObject("name", "Morris Park Bake Shop"),
    new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("zipcode", "10462"))
);
```

If I try to lookup the document with the ObjectId, it never works as it doesn't match any document.

```
mongoDB.getCollection("restaurants").updateOne(
    new BasicDBObject("_id", "56110fe1f882142d842b2a63"),
    new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("zipcode", "10462"))
);
```

Is it possible to make this query work with Object IDs?

I agree that my question is a bit similar to [How to query documents using "_id" field in Java mongodb driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797935/how-to-query-documents-using-id-field-in-java-mongodb-driver) however I am not getting any errors while trying to update a document. It just doesn't match anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query documents using "\_id" field in Java mongodb driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797935/how-to-query-documents-using-id-field-in-java-mongodb-driver)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're currently trying to update based on a string, not an ObjectId.

Make sure to initialise a new ObjectId from the string when building your query:

```
mongoDB.getCollection("restaurants").updateOne(
    new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId("56110fe1f882142d842b2a63")),
    new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("zipcode", "10462"))
);
```

Comment: I missed that. Thanks for your help, problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

@sheilak's answer is the best one but,

You could use {"_id", {"$oid","56110fe1f882142d842b2a63"}} as the filter for the update query if you want it to be in the string format

Comment: Can you explain me a bit how can I use below document to updateOne:-


```{
 "_id": {
  "$oid": "6148079b34f0a9e6mhghkgjvjh"
 },
 "CUST_CODE": "in1",
 "name": "emp1",
 "designation": "tester",
 "address": {
  "Street": "main1",
  "country": "CN"
 }
}```

Answer (score -1):

Convert the string to objectid:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
db.collection.find_one({"_id":ObjectId('5a61bfadef860e4bf266edb2')})

{u'_id': ObjectId('5a61bfadef860e4bf266edb2'), ...
```

Comment: Could you please provide clarity on what you're doing there? and please use code formatting where you should I'm not even sure how to sort this answer out

Comment: Looks like Python. The question is about Java.