# mongodb not able to update below request data using java

Tags: mongodb

Below is the my JSON request data and I want to update currency and subAmount. I tried but it did not updating properly.

Here is my code:

```
{
    "mid":"5032219",
    "description" : "Sample description",
    "currency" : "INR",
    "amount" : {
        "subAmount":"20"
    }
}
```

I tried using below code,
passing the params values are - {currency=AUG, amount={"subAmount":"20.00"}}
public void updateInvoiceModel(InvoiceModel model, Map param) {

```
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("invoice");
        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("invoiceNumber", model.getInvoiceNumber());
        BasicDBObject updateFields = new BasicDBObject();
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : param.entrySet()) {
            updateFields.append(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        BasicDBObject setQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        setQuery.append("$set", updateFields);
        collection.updateOne(searchQuery, setQuery);
```

}
Kindly let me know if anyone have a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a document in MongoDB using ObjectID in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933344/how-to-update-a-document-in-mongodb-using-objectid-in-java)

Comment: Please include what you tried

Comment: no one have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following:

```
db.collection_name.update(
   { _id: mid },
   { $set:
      {
         "currency" : "INR", "amount" : { "subAmount":"20" }
      }
   }
)
```

Comment: This is not Java.

Comment: i have requested to update using java code not using mongodb