# Find by Id in custom query - Mongo Java MongoRepository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-java

I have this query but I'm not getting any result

```
@Query(value = " { '_id': { $in: ?0 }} ", fields = " { response : 1 } ")
public List<SimulatedCase> findByIdWithoutTrace(List<String> ids);
```

I found examples like this

[How to query documents using "_id" field in Java mongodb driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797935/how-to-query-documents-using-id-field-in-java-mongodb-driver)

But can't find how to do it in this way, convert every object in the array into a ObjectId().

Comment: Change argument to `List<ObjectId> ids` and pass ObjectIds from invoking class.

Comment: Thanks, it worked in that way!