# How access any column using objectID in groovy?

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

I have stored `ObjectId("5e0f216aab9234688b125ac1")` in a variable i.e. complete value, and in following code I am trying to access `EmployeeOID` which is an integer.

```
try {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = vars.getObject("collection");
Document result = collection.find(eq("_id",'completeValue').first());
log.info (result)
if(result !=null){

vars.put ("Employeeoid", result.get("EmployeeOID").tointeger());
log.info (Employeeoid)
return "Employeeoid=" + Employeeoid;
}
```

IAm getting this error:

```
Response code: 500
Response message: Exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature 
of method: com.mongodb.client.model.Filters$SimpleEncodingFilter.first() is 
applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: print(java.io.PrintWriter), print(java.lang.Object), 
find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), is(java.lang.Object), 
printf(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;)
```

Comment: try `findOne(...)`

Comment: @injecteer

No luck! 
Document result = collection.findone(eq("_id",'completeValue'))

Error:
Response code: 500
Response message: Exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.findone() is applicable for argument types: (com.mongodb.client.model.Filters$SimpleEncodingFilter) values: [Filter{fieldName='_id', value=completeValue}]
Possible solutions: find(), find(), findAll(), find(com.mongodb.client.ClientSession), find(java.lang.Class), find(org.bson.conversions.Bson)

Answer (score 0):

I believe correct syntax would be:

```
Document result = collection.find(eq("_id", new ObjectId('5e0f216aab9234688b125ac1'))).first()
```

References:

- [How to query documents using “_id” field in Java mongodb driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797935/how-to-query-documents-using-id-field-in-java-mongodb-driver)
- [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/)

Comment: on using this 
Document result = collection.find(eq("_id",vars.get(new ObjectId("id"))))
Iam getting this response:
Response message: Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId: [id]

Comment: Who told you to use `collection.find(eq("_id",vars.get(new ObjectId("id"))))`, I might be suffering from a form of a mental fatigue, however I was under impression I suggested using `collection.find(eq("_id", new ObjectId('5e0f216aab9234688b125ac1')))`

Comment: In my case the hexadecimal string is a dynamic thing actually which I am storing in variable named "id". I cant mention it this way as i don't know what it will be.

Comment: Then you need to use `collection.find(eq("_id",vars.get(new ObjectId(id))))`, Check out [Groovy Documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html) and [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) article to learn more about Groovy scripting.

Comment: I tried:  Document result = collection.find(eq("_id",vars.get(new ObjectId(id))));

but No luck! from the error seems like my sampler is unable to get the variable value from previous sampler( which is actually a value i could see in log)

Error:

Response code: 500
Response message: Exception: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: Script43

Comment: It says that you don't have `id` variable defined. If you're having it in a JMeter Variable which you can access as `${id}` you can use `vars` shorcut in your  script to read the value: `collection.find(eq("_id",vars.get(new ObjectId(vars.get('id')))))`. `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)class instance, check out JavaDoc in particular and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) in general

Comment: id is not a Jmeter variable in my case but i have stored it through following code in previous sampler:

Document result = collection.find(eq("EmployeeOID",1111111)).first();
if(result !=null){
String ID =result.get("_id");  
vars.put("id",ID);
log.info( vars.get("id"))

is there a way I can access this variable?

Comment: The way has been provided in the previous comment.

Comment: On using this 
collection.find(eq("_id",vars.get(new ObjectId(vars.get('id')))))

Response code: 500
Response message: Exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.get() is applicable for argument types: (org.bson.types.ObjectId) values: [5e15b55f0f1421724d092efd]
Possible solutions: get(java.lang.String), grep(), getAt(java.lang.String), grep(java.lang.Object), wait(), any()

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to import FindIterable! it works fine for me

```
FindIterable<Document> EmployeeOID = collection.find(eq("EmployeeOID ", new ObjectId("5e0f216aab9234688b125ac1")));
for (Document doc : EmployeeOID ) {
log.info(doc.get("_id").toString());
 }
```

[mongo][jmeter][groovy]