# Retrieving a single field from MongoDB using Selenium/Java

Tags: mongodb, selenium-webdriver

I'm just switching from MySQL to MongoDB and it's a little confusing. We have our database stored in MongoDB and using Java-Selenium in the front end. I am trying to retrieve just one single data from the database. The code below retrieves all the data present in the database:

```
DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find();

while(cursor.hasNext())
{
    int i=1;
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
    i++;
}
```

This is my database lets say:

```
{
    "name" : "Su_123", 
    "email" : "test@gmail.com", 
    "_id" : ObjectId("12345656565656")
}
```

I want to retrieve just the email field (**test@gmail.com**) from the document where `_id = ObjectId("12345656565656")` and store this in a String field.

How do I go about coding this? `find()` retrieves the entire row.

Comment: Have you looked at the manual? The driver I use allows the use of `find(filter, format)`, where `filter` is what you want to match on, and `format` is the fields you want in the result(s). [See here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

Answer (score 0):

[For newer drivers, since 3.7.1](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/)

---

To get specific document that matches a filter:

```
Document doc = collection.find(eq("email", "test@gmail.com")).first();
```

It can be used to find the first document where the field `email` has the value `test@gmail.com`. And pass an `eq` filter object to specify the equality condition.

[By the same logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47200057/8370915) using `id`:

```
Document document = myCollection.find(eq("_id", new ObjectId("12345656565656"))).first();
```

To get specific value of the field from selected document:

```
String value = (String) doc.get("email");
```

---

For older drivers like [2.14.2](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.14/getting-started/quick-tour/) and [2.13.3](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/)

To get a single document with a query:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("email", "test@gmail.com");

cursor = coll.find(query);

try {
   while(cursor.hasNext()) {
       //System.out.println(cursor.next());
   }
} finally {
   cursor.close();
}
```

---

[To see more details for newer Mongodb Java driver.](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/driver/getting-started/quick-start/)
[To see more details for older Mongodb Java driver.](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.14/getting-started/quick-tour/)
[To see more details from Mongodb Official Docs.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)